# Null Pointer Exception working with Abstract Iterators in Eclipse EMF

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, eclipse-emf

I am struggling to get a multithreaded application working with EMF models. The problem is that, for some reason, the following code throws an unhandled NullPointerException at *next()*:

```
TreeIterator<EObject> i = myEObject.eAllContents();
if (i.hasNext()) {
    EObject o = i.next();
    // Process o...
}
```

This problem only raises in multithreaded applications accessing the EMF resources concurrently. I added thread synchronization through wait()/notify() protecting the function, but I am still getting the same error.

Has any of you had a similar problem? Do you know what are the set of EMF functions that are and are not thread-safe?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You need to give us a test that we can see for ourselves.  Or at the very least more context.

Comment: You should probably put your self-found solution in as an answer rather than an edit. This is allowed. Currently, the question is listed under "unanswered" which doesn't reflect reality.

Answer (score 0):

I located the error: while iterating with eAllContents() EMF does not check for concurrent modifications; however, in this case, I had one. This fact led to the modification of the iterator itself, which in turn ended in a NullPointerException.

Therefore it seems that the *eAllContents()* function should not be used in multithreaded applications. Instead model elements should be accessed through the actual properties of each EClass to avoid this problem.